Is anything implied by the author using the (Greek) phrase translated "work with your hands" in 1 Thessalonians 4:11?
“Work with your hands”
Does Paul mean anything more than "work" (as opposed to "idleness") when he uses the phrase "work with your (own) hands" in 1 Th 4:11
1 Thessalonians 4:9-12 NASB95

Now as to the love of the brethren, you have no need for anyone to write to you, for you yourselves are taught by God to love one another; for indeed you do practice it toward all the brethren who are in all Macedonia. But we urge you, brethren, to excel still more, and to make it your ambition to lead a quiet life and attend to your own business and work with your hands, just as we commanded you, so that you will behave properly toward outsiders and not be in any need. (emphasis added)

I'm curious if it is sensible even to ask the question: What kind of work wouldn't qualify as “work[ing] with your hands?” In other words, was there “work” which would be excluded by “work with your hands?” This is NOT the question I’m asking here. My question is about the Greek. I’ve mentioned my motivation only to suggest the purpose of the question. It might be completely nonsensical to read so much into the Greek/English phrasing.
English Translation(s)
A comparison of English translations of this verse suggests that a straightforward English rendering is "work with your hands."
English Commentators
Based on a survey of some English commentators I could find online (Matthew Henry, Jamieson, Fausset & Brown, Adam Clarke, and others) might suggest that there is nothing remarkable or unusual about this phrase because they do not discuss it much at all, other than to say

Paul wants people not to be idle or worse (busybodies, gossips, ...)
Paul’s audience was of the artisan or working-class

Greek Idiom?
This is primarily a question about the Greek phrase

ἐργάζεσθαι ταῖς ἰδίαις χερσὶν

Is this idiomatic in any way, or is it safe to read the literal English translation as saying something more than "work" (as in, "do not be idle")?
Could Paul have said this any other common way that would have meant the opposite of “idleness?” (I don’t necessarily find synonymous phrase arguments to be thoroughly compelling, but I’m willing to entertain the idea that it could matter.)

Interesting question.  Were there Managers?  Sure.  Was that "work with their hands?"  Did Scribes "work with their hands"?  Did the people who own ships, "work with their hands?"  Tax Gatherers?  Amenuensi? (basically, slaves who were language experts who knew how to write).  Was Paul excluding certain people?  That's very doubtful.   We have to get into their context. It's not like they had a service economy.  They produced goods.  I wonder if the meaning is something close to, "Do productive work," or "Be engaged in producing," or simply  "Produce goods."  Good question.

It should be added that ἰδίαις (own) was either added or deleted from the original, depending on which side of the textual argument you come down on.  The only reason I bring this up is that it seems to me there might be a difference in meaning.   And another question might be, "Did most Excellent Theophilus work with his hands?"  If not, then would Paul exclude him from helping out financially (the context of the OP's verse)?  That doesn't ring true to me.  Sorry, I can't be more helpful.

@MikeSangrey, The real question that I want to answer is whether we should consider what Paul is saying as any sort of advice regarding a career (or hobby) that I should choose or prefer. However, this question is meant to help me decide whether or not Paul is even attempting to offer advice in this regard.

Working remotely by your computer is not what Paul meant by working with your hands.

The answer to this question is provided in the next verse:

1 Thess 4:11, 12 - and to aspire to live quietly, to attend to your
own matters, and to work with your own hands, as we instructed you.
Then you will behave properly toward outsiders, without being
dependent on anyone.

In Paul's era, almost all employment involved some kind of trade where people worked with their hands.  Thus the phrase to "work with your hands" was an idiom for earning one's own living, ie, not being dependent upon others.  Paul actually says this explicitly as quoted above.
That is, Paul is encouraging good Christians, as far as practical, to be financially self sufficient.  Now, there were some important exceptions - widows and orphans should be supported as per 1 Tim 5:1-16, James 1:27.  However, such exceptions merely served to underline the importance of earning living so as to:

be able to provide something for the needy
not place an extra strain on church family resources.

The same instruction is given elsewhere:

Eph 4:28 - He who has been stealing must steal no longer, but must work, doing good with his own hands, that he may have something to share with the one in need.
2 Thess 3:12 - Now we command and exhort to such by our Lord Jesus Christ so that, working with quietness, they may eat their own bread.

Paul himself set an example of this by providing for his own income by working to support himself.  See 1 Cor 9:6, 1 Thess 2:9, 2 Thess 3:7, etc.
Note that the idiom of "working with one's own hands" is further strengthened by its contrast with "stealing" which is gaining a dishonest advantage by others' efforts.  Thus, again, Paul is encouraging Christians to be, as far as practical, self sufficient.

‘ "work with your hands" was a euphemism for earning one's own living ’ That is an assertion that is a direct answer to my question. Can you offer any support for that?

'Euphemism' is not the figure of speech you're looking for.  It's 'metonymy'.  Also, see my answer below, which is, hopefully, to add some support to this answer suggesting an idiom.

@mojo - I thought that was rather obvious based on the following verse as quoted above - see also 2 Thess 3:12 for the same idea.  It is also in contradistinction to "stealing" which is dishonest gain by someone else's effort.

@MikeSangrey - you are correct.  I will update this.

@Dottard Whether the phrase is idiomatic or not is at the heart of my question. While I would prefer additional evidence or reasoning to back up this assertion, it is at least fair to rely on other instances of the phrase so assert that it is synonymous with “earning one’s own living.”

I'd like to add support to Dottard's answer.  I think he's correct.
This is from Louw & Nida's Lexicon based on Semantic Domains.  They list several idioms.  None of them are the idiomatic expression in your question.  However, the use of "hand" in idiomatic expressions is certainly not unusual; and even in composition with other words, was, pardon me, ready at hand to the ancient writers.
χεὶρ ἀνθρωπίνη means 'person'.  Literally, "human hand", but it refers to the person.  See Acts 17.25.  Which translates to: "he does not need anything that people can supply by working for him."
σὺν χειρὶ means 'with the help of'.  Literally, "with hand" (note the singular may be an important linguistic signal)  See Acts 7:35.  Which translates to: "with the help of an angel"
There are several idiomatic expressions which mean arrest.  See Acts 4:3, John 7:30, Luke 22:53.
Luke 9:62 "puts his hand to a plow and looks back" is a Semitic idiom meaning, "one who starts a job and hesitates to finish."
Matthew 26:45  εἰς χεῖρας ἁμαρτωλῶν Literally: "into the hands of sinners." "into the hands" is an idiom that means, "into the control."
I find it interesting that several of these idioms have the connotation of "control".  I would not want to push the idea, but perhaps the idiom in 1 Thes. 4:11 has some sense of "do what you have control over."  Interesting to me is the idea of 'control' is reflected in the next sentence advising to "not be dependent on."
There's also words composed with 'hand' (χειρ-):
χειραγωγέω: lead by hand
χειραγωγός: guide
χειρόγραφον: record of debts
χειροπαίητος: man-made
χειροτονέω: choose or appoint

This verse could be more about Paul admonishing believers to study scripture for the purpose of knowing what they are talking about when delivering the gospel of God's grace to "them that are without".
Notice who Paul is referring to as "them that are without" also here, and the purpose of walking toward them in wisdom:
Colossians 4:3-6

Withal praying also for us, that God would open unto us a door of utterance, to speak the mystery of Christ, for which I am also in bonds:
4 That I may make it manifest, as I ought to speak.
5 Walk in wisdom toward them that are without, redeeming the time.
6 Let your speech be always with grace, seasoned with salt, that ye may know how ye ought to answer every man.

To study "to be quiet" would be to study to the point of being able to discern fact from fiction in the moment of need, 'in season or out' (2 Timothy 4:2).  God's ministers of reconciliation (2 Corinthians 5:18) need to be with "lack of nothing" regarding scriptural understanding.  Rather than just taking someone's word on something scriptural, students of scripture are to do their "own business", and "prove all things" (1 Thessalonians 5:21).  Followers of Paul's gospel are figuratively using their our "own hands", or doing their own work, when studying in this fashion, much like a Berean (Acts 17:10-11)!
It is about not being lazy when studying for the purpose of accurate teaching, rather than someone who may just be 'going with the flow', so to speak (Ephesians 4:11-16).  Paul admonishes study again in 2 Timothy 2:15, so believers may show themselves "approved unto God".
Below is the KJV of the verses in question.  Notice how it retains the word "own", in "own hands", Greek idios, which is of importance in keeping Paul's point in proper context:
1 Thessalonians 4:10-12

And indeed ye do it toward all the brethren which are in all Macedonia: but we beseech you, brethren, that ye increase more and more;
11 And that ye study to be quiet, and to do your own business, and to work with your own hands, as we commanded you;
12 That ye may walk honestly toward them that are without, and that ye may have lack of nothing.

In verse 10 above, Paul is admonishing the "brethren" to increase more and more in knowledge for the purpose of gaining more brethren, to grow in number of believers.  He would be asking them to go to "them that are without" (unbelievers) honestly, meaning to share the gospel of God's grace as accurately as possible by work of their study.  This is the primary purpose of Christ's ambassadors (2 Corinthians 5:20), and the work they are admonished to do is to diligently learn and teach the gospel of God's grace and faith in Christ crucified:
Ephesians 6:10-19

Finally, my brethren, be strong in the Lord, and in the power of his might.
11 Put on the whole armour of God, that ye may be able to stand against the wiles of the devil.
12 For we wrestle not against flesh and blood, but against principalities, against powers, against the rulers of the darkness of this world, against spiritual wickedness in high places.
13 Wherefore take unto you the whole armour of God, that ye may be able to withstand in the evil day, and having done all, to stand.
14 Stand therefore, having your loins girt about with truth, and having on the breastplate of righteousness;
15 And your feet shod with the preparation of the gospel of peace;
16 Above all, taking the shield of faith, wherewith ye shall be able to quench all the fiery darts of the wicked.
17 And take the helmet of salvation, and the sword of the Spirit, which is the word of God:
18 Praying always with all prayer and supplication in the Spirit, and watching thereunto with all perseverance and supplication for all saints;
19 And for me, that utterance may be given unto me, that I may open my mouth boldly, to make known the mystery of the gospel,


Can you provide some evidence or reasoning behind the initial thesis, "This verse is more about..."? Why is this understanding preferable to a "plain" reading that might suggest that he's talking about vocation/work/chores?

@mojo It is based on the other scripture I stated, but I am revising it to "could be" rather than "is".  Thanks for the input!

You've made what could be a successful application (Christ's ambassadors should be serious about their study of the Scriptures), but I don't see the reasoning behind the assertion that this is what Paul is speaking about when he is writing to the believers in Thessalonica. Does the context in 1 Thessalonians suggest that Paul is speaking figuratively about evangelism? A simple/naïve reading of this passage might be that Paul's speaking about physical work (vocation, etc.). What makes your reading of this preferable to that?

@mojo Honestly, I have read it multiple times and I can see it being either, but my reasoning primarily has to do with Paul's admonishment for believers to study.  Also, his verse prior: Thes 4:10 "And indeed ye do it toward all the brethren which are in all Macedonia: but we beseech you, brethren, that ye increase more and more;" Paul is beseeching the brethren to increase...in believers.  He is telling them to preach the gospel.  Also in truth, "walking honestly toward them that are without" is a key statement to support this.  "Them that are without" could also be referring to unbelievers.

@mojo It wouldn't make sense to "work with your own hands" in the sense of laboring for food, clothing, etc...for "them that are without". If they are without anything to offer you...for your work, then what is he talking about? I feel pretty good that this is all about "obedience to the faith", preaching the gospel of God's grace accurately (honestly)... (Rom 1:5, Rom 16:16, 2 Tim 4:2, Eph 6:10-17).

I'm not attempting to debate the issue here; rather to suggest that you include this reasoning in your answer.

@mojo Done!  Thanks for the suggestion!
